# Paypal redirects to success after payment without adding it to the database

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've recently used this guide:

http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

and what I realized is that it goes properly in the paypal website, and when the payment is made - it redirects to "payment successful" page.

the problem is, it doesn't do the "payments.php the response part", so it doesn't add the payment into the database.

Here's the code of payments.php

```
<?php
// Database variables
$host = "localhost"; //database location
$user = "xxx"; //database username
$pass = "xxx"; //database password
$db_name = "xxx"; //database name

// PayPal settings
$paypal_email = 'sawickipiotr2000-facilitator-1@gmail.com';
$return_url = 'http://leagueaccountsbot.tk/elements/payment-successful.html';
$cancel_url = 'http://leagueaccountsbot.tk/elements/payment-cancelled.html';
$notify_url = 'http://leagueaccountsbot.tk/elements/payments.php';

$item_name = 'League Accounts Bot';
$item_amount = 5.00;

// Include Functions
include("functions.php");

// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
    $querystring = '';

    // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    // Append querystring with custom field
    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();
} else {
    //Database Connection
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name);
    // Response from Paypal

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR

    } else {
        fputs($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                // Used for debugging
                // mail('user@domain.com', 'PAYPAL POST - VERIFIED RESPONSE', print_r($post, true));

                // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
                $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
                if ($valid_txnid && $valid_price) {

                    $orderid = updatePayments($data);

                    if ($orderid) {
                        // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database
                    } else {
                        // Error inserting into DB
                        // E-mail admin or alert user
                        // mail('user@domain.com', 'PAYPAL POST - INSERT INTO DB WENT WRONG', print_r($data, true));
                    }
                } else {
                    // Payment made but data has been changed
                    // E-mail admin or alert user
                }

            } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

                // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!
                // E-mail admin or alert user

                // Used for debugging
                //@mail("user@domain.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Invalid Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");
            }
        }
    fclose ($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe I did something wrong in PayPal settings of the account? I've set the IPN to "http://www.leagueaccountsbot.tk/elements/payments.php" and after successful payment the page is: "/elements/successful.html?amt=5.00&cc=USD&item_name=League%20Accounts%20Bot&item_number=1&st=Completed&tx=4KG186895E5344708"

Comment: Maybe it never enter the condition to execute `updatePayments`

Comment: @Hackerman I guessed so, but I have no idea why.

Comment: You can add a couple of messages in order to check if your code get executed to that part...for example, right below your `$fp = fsockopen` line, add this one `var_dump($fp);`

Comment: I tried sending en E-Mail right after  $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
 mysql_select_db($db_name); but it didn't work, so it can't be achieved.